# How to find the visual studio 2012 .exe

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, installation, windows-server-2008-r2

I've downloaded and installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 (In the official microsoft partner website) in a windows server 2012 R2 but im unable to access the .exe because i can't find it.

[image]

[image]

The installation ends correctly without error: 
[image]

Problem is that i can't see the .exe at the location it should be.

[image]

I've done many search on my computer, unistall-reinstall-repair but impossible to find a solution.

In the 11.0 solution, only a "Blend" file is visible...
[image]

Any clue ?

Comment: VS 2012 is 11.0 so have you tried checking in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE"

Comment: In the microsoft partner official website !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was finally a problem of the ISO i took, i changed, redownload it and now it works. 
Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2012 is actually version number 11.0 as you can [see here for version numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#History).

That means (assuming you haven't installed it in the non-standard location - if that is even possible) you will want to look in:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE

You will find the executable to be called:

> devenv.exe

Comment: No, actually i also searched in already but i only have a "blend" file. I should have precised it that's actually my problem.

Comment: @Bouh10: You say you "downloaded" it... have you actually *installed* it?

Comment: Yes obviously, if not the VS 11.0 file will not appear. 
The only devenv.exe i find with a search is in the VS 2010. Do you think that the 2010 version could create this issue ?

Comment: What "VS 11.0" file? I don't see one

Comment: Actually i already have a 2010 version installed. You can see it in the path in the update of my post.

Comment: There is no problem with having VS 2010 and 2012 installed simultaneously. Clearly you are not installing it correctly, or your installation is failing, @bouh10. There isn't enough information given in the question to solve the problem.

Comment: Yes i understand. 
Basically what information do you need ? It's sure it comes from the installation because i can't see it in the programs ?

Comment: @Bouh10: Well go through the installation process, and see what it says during the process. It will tell you if there are problems, or if it installs correctly. And to be clear, I am talking about running "VS2012.4.exe"

Comment: @musefan I edited the post with screenshots of the installation. Nothing to report.